# webpack - syntactic errors appear encoded in browser console, not in shell (terminal)

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-3

when there's a syntax error, for some reason it appears scrambled in the console, but not in the terminal. Not using any extra modules in webpack. Tried googling but can't find anyone having the same issue. [image]

using webpack 3.5.5

Please see the difference below:

Comment: Is this for a react app? If so do you have the right presets set in your webpack config file? `presets:['es2015','react']`

Comment: yes, its for react and all those plugins are included